# UWP playing a .aif file with AudioGraph

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to play a sound with audio graph and it is failing on creating a file output node from a storage file. I have checked and the storage file is not null; The error I am getting is just unknown error and is of no help

Any ideas?

```
private async void HandlePlayCommand()
{
    if (_audioGraph == null)
    {
        var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        var createResults = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
        if (createResults.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success) return;

        _audioGraph = createResults.Graph;

        var deviceResult = await _audioGraph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if(deviceResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success) return;

        var outputNode = deviceResult.DeviceOutputNode;
       StorageFile file = await GetStorageFiles();

        var fileResult = await _audioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file);
        if (fileResult.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success) return;

        var fileInputNode = fileResult.FileInputNode;

        fileInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(outputNode);


        _audioGraph.Start();
    }
}

private async Task<StorageFile> GetStorageFiles()
{
    string CountriesFile = @"Assets\909_1.aif";
    StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(CountriesFile);

    return file;
}
```

Comment: `string CountriesFile = @"Assets\909_1.aif";` should be `string CountriesFile = "ms-appx:///Assets/909_1.aif";`

Comment: Could you please convert your audio files to `.wav`, `.mp3`,`.wna` or some other else? I guess `.aif` is not supported.

Comment: That was correct, it was the file type. Strange as I could play the .aif by double clicking it in the project. Anyway works now. If you put that up as a solution ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing on my side,  I'm afraid the `.aif` format currently is not supported by [`AudioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/audiograph_createfileinputnodeasync_overload.aspx) method. The formats sure to be supported that are `.mp3`,`.wav`,`.wna`,`.m4a` and so on. So the solution maybe change the audio files to other formats.

More details please reference the [audio official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation).